# deriving screen-space coordinates in glsl shader

Tags: opengl, glsl, texture-mapping, render-to-texture

I'm trying to write a simple application for baking a texture from a paint buffer. Right now I have a mesh, a mesh texture, and a paint texture. When I render the mesh, the mesh shader will lookup the mesh texture and then based on the screen position of the fragment lookup the paint texture value. I then composite the paint lookup with the mesh lookup.

Here's a screenshot with nothing in the paint buffer and just the mesh texture.

[image: Just the mesh texture]

Here's a screenshot with something in the paint buffer composited over the mesh texture.

[image: Screen-space paint texture composited over mesh texture]

So that all works great, but I'd like to bake the paint texture into my mesh texture. Right now I send the mesh's UVs down as the position with an ortho set to (0,1)x(0,1) so I'm actually doing everything in texture space. The mesh texture lookup is also the position. The problem I'm having though is computing the screen space position of the fragment from the original projection to figure out where to sample the paint texture. I'm passing the bake shader my original camera project matrices and the object position to send the fragment shader the device-normalized position of the fragment (again from my original camera projection) to do the lookup, but it's coming out funny.

Here's what the bake texture is generating if I render half the output using the paint texture and screen position I've derived.

[image: Half mesh texture, half screen-space texture using bake shader]

I would expect that block line to be right down the middle.

Am I calculating the screen position incorrectly in my vertex shader? Or am I going about this in a fundamentally wrong way?

```
    // vertex shader
uniform mat4 orthoPV;
uniform mat4 cameraPV;
uniform mat4 objToWorld;
varying vec2 uv;
varying vec2 screenPos;
void main() {
  uv = gl_Vertex.xy;
  screenPos = 0.5 * (vec2(1,1) + (cameraPV * objToWorld * vec4(gl_MultiTexCoord0.xyz,1)).xy);
  screenPos = gl_MultiTexCoord0.xy;
  gl_Position = orthoPV * gl_Vertex;
  gl_FrontColor = vec4(1,0,0,1);
}

// fragment shader
uniform sampler2D meshTexture;
uniform sampler2D paintTexture;
varying vec2 uv;
varying vec2 screenPos;
void main() {
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(meshTexture, uv);
    if (screenPos.x > .5)
        gl_FragColor = texture2D(paintTexture, uv);
}
```

Comment: You forgot the division by w whne going from clip space to NDC.

Comment: I am a little confused as to why you do not just use `gl_FragCoord`? That would *actually* be in screen-space as your title suggests, whereas what you are trying to do right now appears to be in normalized texture coordinates.

Comment: @Andon I use gl_FragCoord in the mesh rendering pass so I don't need to derive it. In the second pass I'm rendering in texture space and the gl_FragCoord doesn't correlate to the paint texture in screen space of my model.

Comment: Ah, okay. Yeah, I see your point now. `gl_Position` is computed using a completely different projection matrix. You do need to divide by `w` after projection though as derhass points out.

Comment: @Andon/derhass: The w-division is a mistake, which I've corrected, but the images look the same.